# Install older version of software and dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, r

I need to install `R` 3.0.2 because a needed library isn't compatible with 3.0.3 yet (the latest).

I can install the older version of R like so:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
```

However all the dependencies of r-base try and install with 3.0.3

```
root@foo:~# apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.0.2-1precise0) but 3.0.3-1precise0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I install r-base 3.0.2 and all the dependencies as 3.0.2 ?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0 r-recommended=3.0.2-1precise0`?

Answer (score 5):

- First remove the packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove r-base
  ```
- A bit of cleaning

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- Reinstall **R** forcing an older version

  ```
  sudo apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but it looks like 3.0.3 is still installed. Could this be a problem with the package? Full output here: https://gist.github.com/spuder/f7b05b3e742494f8a4d9

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`.Try it and again install R

Comment: did you want this `3.0.2-1precise`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to take care of the `r-recommended=3.0.2-1precise0` dependency... While one could manually also list installing that older version, this is not feasible when a package has many old dependencies

Comment: Its quite silly one has to remove or install the required version on top of the current one? Why it seems here is no decent multi-version manager for R in linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade packages by simply installing over the top. apt is smart enough to handle this properly.

To install R 3.0.2 I ran dpkg -S /usr/bin/R and found that the binary was provided by `r-base-core`. Downgrading that fixed the issue

```
apt-get install r-base-core=3.0.2-1precise0  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  r-cran-foreign ...
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  ess r-doc-info r-doc-pdf r-mathlib
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  r-base r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-recommended
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  r-base-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 9 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.5 MB of archives.


apt-get install r-base=3.0.2-1precise0
...
apt-get install r-recommended=3.0.2-1precise0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Universe" repository from software and updates and then run the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: When he will re enable universe repo and then try updating or upgrading, won't he have some (dependency) problem again?

Comment: Once installed, after that he won't get any dependency errors.

Comment: see [this](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/rdev) link, marutter PPA contains the specified `r-base` package version.