# Installing base R version 4.0.5 on ubuntu

Tags: apt, r

I currently have R 4.2.1, but I am trying to install 4.0.5

4.2.1 can be removed, but I can't seem to specify R 4.0.5 when installing.

Any input is appreciated.

This is what I attempted so far:

- [Install older version of software and dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435232/install-older-version-of-software-and-dependencies)

Info:
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: is this helpful? https://pkgs.org/search/?q=R%204.0.5

Comment: You mean 4.1.2 rther than 4.2.1? If yes, then please edit your question to correct. Also indicate what version of Ubuntu you are using and whether your current version is installed through the default software repositories or not.

Comment: @vanadium I have R 4.2.1 installed on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I am not sure if I am using the default repos. I will report back

Comment: @24601 So I found base R here: https://altlinux.pkgs.org/p10/classic-x86_64/R-base-4.0.5-alt1.x86_64.rpm.html I am not familiar with this website, what would be the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if you need another version of R in your system, then I would suggest you use Anaconda / Miniconda.

What you will end up doing is be able to create multiple environments, each of which can have a different set of programs.  You can switch between them easily.  And each can have different versions of programs (such as R).

You can [decide](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html#anaconda-or-miniconda) which one you want.  I would suggest Miniconda.

You can download it [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).  I suggest you get the latest one (version 3.9 of Python).

Below the download link is a set of installation [instructions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

After you've installed it (pick the default options if you don't know what to answer with), I believe it will ask you to log out and log back in.  Basically, you will need to let any environments take effect.  What you will find is that the `conda` executable is in your path.  (i.e., type `which conda`)

Honestly, I suggest you go through the conda documentation to see what you can or cannot do.  But I'll just get to the point to answer your question.

[Create](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) an environment using the command `conda create -n myenv`.

After you let it do its work, you can then **switch** to the environment by doing `conda activate myenv`.  You will now see `(myenv)` in the far left side of your prompt.  To leave this and go back to your system level software, do a `conda deactivate`.

Anyway, `R` is [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base) within Anaconda.  While you're in the `myenv` environment, type `conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.0.5`.

Type `which R` when you're either within or outside of the environment.  This will let you know which R you're using.  Personally, I think this is far safer than playing around with the R version that is for your version of Ubuntu.  You can also go ahead in another separate environment, if such a version is available.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984676/how-to-downgrade-r-version-3-2-2-to-version-3-1-1-on-ubuntu

Instead of `1precise0` I used what the output looked like from `apt-cache showpkg r-base`

For me it was: `sudo apt-get install r-base-core=4.0.5-1.2004.0c`

Comment: The question is not how to downgrade R, but how to downgrade R from 4.2.1 to 4.0.5. You may want to delete your answer.

Comment: I can edit the question to clarify the problem, which is: the default R installation is 4.2.1 (newest) in `apt-get install` but is wasn't clear how to install a specific version of r. In my case, I wanted 4.0.5. The link I provided shows how to specify the version, but explains how to script it. i.e. including Ubuntu installation (`1precise0`). Should I edit the question?