# How to re-install R 4.2.0

Tags: r

I have been running R version 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Recently R was updated to 4.3.0 on my system, but for my current work I need to return to version 4.2.0. I uninstalled R using the instructions linked below, performed the cleaning step, and altered the command in step 3 to the following:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=4.2.0
```

I tried a few variations on this command including `sudo apt-get install r-base=4.2.0-1precise0`, but all gave me the message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.2.0' for 'r-base' was not found
```

[Install older version of software and dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435232/install-older-version-of-software-and-dependencies)

Does anyone know the correct code to reinstall R 4.2.0?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to see exact available versions using `apt policy r-base` - to get R 4.x on Ubuntu 20.04 you probably enabled a 3rd party repository (most likely the `focal-cran40` repo) so the numbering convention may be something like `4.2.0-1.2004.0`